# How to modify the web-browsing history through a python script?

Tags: python, sqlite, google-chrome

I want to programatically modify the browsing history of Chrome through a Python code.

I already knew that many browsers use sqllite database for the browsing history. And asked google and all the answers and questions were about importing/exporting the data of the browsing history.

However what I want to do is to modify the data in the database to delete specific or all the sites that I've visited.
I would like to ask you if there was some modules in Python that helps doing the task through code.

If not applicable then we will need to switch into making the code take control over the mouse and the screen, open chrome, go to the browsing history, select the rows wanted deleted and press delete/confirm. Which will be impossible for a beginner like me to gather the determination and resources to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful [How can I delete all web history that matches a specific query in Google Chrome](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
it uses javascript, but you can easily translate it into some simple python and use something like BS [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or just scroll down and there's some sql things going on which look promising

And because you'll have the code already in one language translating it should be pretty simple, even for a beginner and especially using python. PS this took me about as long to find as it was to read your question. it's rare that you will want to do something that someone hasn't already done..just maybe not in python ;)